# Exception caught during execution of push command

Tags: gradle, grgit

I have a task :

```
task tagRepo1 << {
logger.info("adding tag in the repo")

def buildNumber = '545'
if (!buildNumber) {
    // not to be executed outside build system
    throw new Exception('tagRepo should only be executed via build, no build number found')
}

def gitTagName = 'tag1'
if (!gitTagName) {
    throw new Exception('gitTagName is not set')
}

def gitTagMessage = 'someMessage'
if (!gitTagMessage) {
    // default message
    gitTagMessage = 'default tagging message'
}

def gitUserName = 'user'
if (!gitUserName) {
    throw new Exception('gitUserName is not set')
}

 def gitPassword = 'password'
if (!gitPassword) {
    throw new Exception('gitPassword is not set')
}

def credentials = new org.ajoberstar.grgit.Credentials(gitUserName,gitPassword)

def grgit = org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit.open(dir: project.rootDir.absolutePath, creds: credentials)

def remotes = grgit.remote.list()
logger.info('git remotes size - ' + remotes.size())
logger.info('git remotes - ' + remotes)

def central = remotes.find { it.name == 'central' }
if (!central) {
    def gitRepoLocation = 'location'

    if (!gitRepoLocation) {
        throw new Exception('gitRepoLocation is not set')
    }

    grgit.remote.add(name: 'central', url: gitRepoLocation)
}

grgit.tag.add(name: gitTagName, message: gitTagMessage)
grgit.push(remote: 'central', tags: true)
}
```

But when I execute this task, I get error while pushing the tag 
`Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.JGitInternalException: Exception caught during execution of push command`. Any ideas why this issue comes

If I do `--stacktrace`, I get this output:

```
*Exception is:
 org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':core:tagRepo1'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.JGitInternalException: Exception  caught during execution of push command
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.PushCommand.call(PushCommand.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.PushCommand.call(PushCommand.java:80)
    at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.ajoberstar.grgit.operation.PushOp.call(PushOp.groovy:114)
    at org.ajoberstar.grgit.operation.PushOp.call(PushOp.groovy)
    at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)
    at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.ajoberstar.grgit.util.OpSyntaxUtil.tryOp(OpSyntaxUtil.groovy:45)
    at org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit.methodMissing(Grgit.groovy:188)
    at build_5ti1avic8c4zg9l8osnwfpqdj$_run_closure3.doCall(C:\Users\Byteorigin\Documents\corepro\core\build.gradle:264)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:548)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:529)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskMutator$1.execute(TaskMutator.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskMutator$1.execute(TaskMutator.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.NotSupportedException: remote does not support smart HTTP push
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openPush(TransportHttp.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PushProcess.execute(PushProcess.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.push(Transport.java:1200)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.PushCommand.call(PushCommand.java:157)
    ... 62 more
```

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly to your updated question.

Comment: Hey, I saw the answer. But even if I use ssh , I get an error: Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.NotSupportedException: remote does not support smart HTTP push
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openPush(TransportHttp.java:398)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PushProcess.execute(PushProcess.java:154)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.push(Transport.java:1200)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.api.PushCommand.call(PushCommand.java:157)

Comment: Are you sure? What is the output of `git remote -v`? Just changing your project property `gitRepoLocation` will not be enough as it is only used if there is no remote with name `central` defined yet.

Comment: It worked, if I remove remote:central from grgit.push(remote: 'central', tags: true).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start gradle with `-i` or `-d` to get more output about what is happening to find an eventual cause. Also or alternatively add `-s` to get the full stacktrace of the catched exception displayed to find the root cause of your issue. If you still need help after that, add more of the info retrieved to your question.

**UPDATE:**
Well, as your full stacktrace reveals, you have your remote configured with an HTTP URL but the Git server does not support pushing via HTTP which would have to be enabled explicitly. So you cannot push anything to this remote, not only the tag that is created by `grgit`. Change the URL of your remote with `git remote --set-url <url>` to an URL that supports pushing like an `ssh:` or `git:` URL, depending on the Git server you are trying to use.